# read in properties on beforepageload

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to read a value from a properties file in the beforepageload event. unfortunately I load the properties file as a variable via a theme but ofcourse this does not work because it is not available yet.

Is there anoter way to read in the file via SSJS ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567642/how-to-use-xpages-translation-files-from-lotusscript-and-ssjs-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the properties file as a "bundle" to the XPage's resources:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:bundle src="/XYZ.properties" var="XYZ"></xp:bundle>
</xp:this.resources>
```

and directly get any of its property values with:

```
var propvalue = XYZ.propkey;
```